# Codeigniter Page Content Unsuccessfully Loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter

Since I am newbie in Codeigniter, I've got problem for my URI format.

I have url : myweb/admin/
If I write the URL :

```
myweb/admin/
myweb/admin/index
```

My page cotent is perfectly loaded.

But when I write like this:

```
myweb/admin
myweb/admin/index/
```

My page content is mess and when I open browser console, I got message about I failed to load resurces (CSS, JS , etc.)
Can you tell me what I've missed?

Comment: Use absolute path for css files linking or relative ones that start with `/` - meaning root of server/website.

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess have some like this

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)
```

?

to overriden the rewrite conf to this folders? (where assets is a folder with css, jquery, images ... )

Answer (score 0):

For including all your files (css, img, etc.), you should use:

```
<?php echo base_url('path/to/file.css'); ?>
```

Relative to the defined base_url() in config.php, and then it will work even if it's moved to another folder.